# Customize kibana 4 and check for changes to be reflected before making a build

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have just started exploring kibana 4. I am trying to make few UI  modifications like removing the kibana icon in the nav bar. After making the changes,we need to prepare a build. I went through the 'CONTRIBUTING.md' file under kibana repo, where they have provided instructions on how to prepare a build. But it takes some time(10 to 15 min) to prepare a build after the changes.Is there any way where i can make the changes and see if the changes are working fine before making a build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Kibana 4.3-snapshot.Not sure what was the issue.I cloned a fresh copy from here : https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git 
Ran the following commands and could see the development server running.

```
nvm install 0.12 

npm install 

npm start
```

@Pigueiras Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `grunt dev` instead of `grunt build`, you will start a development server where each change in the code you do will be reflected. After executing it, you just have to go to your browser and enter in http://localhost:5601.

**EDIT:** It looks like now it's different than when I used to work on it. Try with `npm start`. Better to check the instructions in the source by the way: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: I tried grunt dev in the top level directory and i got this error :            Warning: Task "dev" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.                                                                            Did i miss something ? It used to work with 4.1.2 version but has stopped working with 4.3.

Comment: @ranjansaga Yes, you're right. Check my edit, it looks they changed the way the development server is started.

Comment: I followed the instructions given in the CONTRIBUTING.md, But nothing works when i give npm start. It is stuck there. I can't see the server running at http://localhost:5601. I also tried making a kibana.dev.yml file which is a copy of kibana.yml . It did not work. Did i miss something ?